# restarting a queue of API requests if a token refresh happened

Tags: redux, jwt, redux-thunk, redux-saga, refresh-token

I'm having a hard time wrapping my brain around this pattern I am trying to implement so I'm hoping the stack overflow community might be able to help me work through a solution to this.

Currently I use `redux-thunk` along with `superagent` to handle calls to me API and syncing it all up with redux

An example of this might look like

```
export const getUser = (id) => {
  return (dispatch) => {
    const deferred = new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
      const call = () => {
        API.get(`/users/${id}`)
        .then((response) => response.body)
        .then((response) => {
          if (response.message === 'User found') {
            serializeUser(response.data).then((response) => {
              resolve(response);
            });
          } else {
            reject('not found');
          }
        }).catch((err) => {
          handleCatch(err, dispatch).then(call).catch(reject)
        });
      }
      call()
    });
    return deferred;
  };
};
```

In the case where the server comes back with a 200 and some data I continue on with putting the data into the store and rendering to the page or whatever my application does.

In the case I receive an error I have attempted to write a function that will intercept those and determine if it should show an error on page or in the case of a 401 from our API, attempt a token refresh and then try to recall the method...

```
import { refreshToken } from '../actions/authentication';

export default (err, dispatch) => {
  const deferred = new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    if (err.status === 401) {
      dispatch(refreshToken()).then(resolve).catch(reject)
    } else {
      reject(err);
    }
  })
  return deferred;
};
```

This works, however, I have to add this to each call, and it doesn't account for concurrent calls that should not attempt to call if there is a refresh in progress.

I've seen some things in my research on this topic that maybe `redux-saga` could work but I haven't been able to wrap my brain around how I might make this work

Basically, I need something like a queue that all my API requests will go into that is maybe debounced so any concurrent requests will just be pushed to the end and once a timeout ends the calls get stacked up, when the first call gets a 401 it pauses the queue until the token refresh either comes back successful, in which case it continues the queue, or with a failure, in which case it cancels all future requests from the queue and sends the user back to a login page

The thing I would be worried about here is if the first call in the stack takes a long time, I don't want the other calls to then have to wait a long time because it will increase the perceived loading time to the user

Is there a better way to handle keeping tokens refreshed?

Comment: Did you get this figured out? How did you do it?